# Call C++(C) from D language

Tags: c++, c, d

How do you call a C++ function from a D program?
What commands should I use?
I'm trying to use `dmd` on Fedora.

Comment: Try looking at http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html, although it seems to work only with C. You can look at proposals here on how to interface to C++: http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html

Comment: I looked at that tutorial. It missed description about .di file. Thanks for Vlad who shares with me solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simplest example I can think of, if you're calling C functions:

```
$ cat a.c
int f(int a, int b){
    return a + b + 42;
}
$ cat a.di
extern (C):
int f(int, int);
$ cat b.d
import std.stdio;
import a;
void main(){
    writeln( f( 100, 1000) );
}
$ gcc -c a.c
$ dmd b.d a.o
$ ./b
1142
$
```

If you're using shared objects, you could so something like:

```
$ cat sdltest.di
module sdltest;

extern (C):

struct SDL_version{
    ubyte major;
    ubyte minor;
    ubyte patch;
}

SDL_version * SDL_Linked_Version();

$ cat a.d
import std.stdio;
import sdltest;

void main(){
    SDL_version *ver = SDL_Linked_Version();
    writefln("%d.%d.%d", ver.major, ver.minor, ver.patch);
}

$ dmd a.d -L-lSDL
$ ./a
1.2.14
$
```

In this example, I linked with an [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) function. The `-L` argument to `dmd` allows you to pass arguments to [`ld`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ld), in this case `-lSDL` to link with SDL.

D interface files (`.di`) are described [here](http://dlang.org/dmd-windows.html#interface_files).

You should also take a look at [htod](http://dlang.org/htod.html).

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much. It works. What is .di file? I haven't read about it before.

Comment: So, for example, to use libxml I need to write bindings for functions that I'm going to use, right?

Comment: @StanislavFeldman: I think so, unless somebody's done it before. Some popular libraries already have D bindings. Do you specifically need libxml? D has a [`std.xml`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_xml.html) module. I've also added a compilation example with shared libraries.

Comment: @StanislavFeldman : .di files are D source files that contain function signatures. Think of them as C/C++ header files. In order to write a binding to some C / C++ library you *do not* need .di file(s). They are much more important when you have your own D library, and you need to give an interface to it to your clients.

Comment: I didn't understand you. You gave sample with .di file, but now you say I don't need it to create bindings to C/C++ lib.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with me std.xml module. Is it suitable for html parsing?

Comment: @StanislavFeldman: That was DejanLekic who said you didn't need the `.di`. He's right in that you can just put your signatures in an `extern(C){...}` inside your `.d` file. But if there are a lot of them, a separate `.di` file is probably cleaner.

Comment: There's also an XML parser in Tango, supposedly a lot [faster](http://dotnot.org/blog/archives/2008/03/12/why-is-dtango-so-fast-at-parsing-xml/): [look here](http://dsource.org/projects/tango/docs/stable/). Unfortunately, I haven't used any of them, so I can't help further. But I would say that HTML is less strict than XML, so unless you're parsing [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML), an XML parser might not be the best solution.

Comment: @StanislavFeldman, you also have a very nice XML parser called kxml - http://opticron.no-ip.org/svn/branches/kxml/ . Some people even wanted to replace `std.xml` with Opticron's XML parser.