# C and D communication

Tags: c, d

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062750/call-cc-from-d-language) in order to do my approach

I have a file: software_pluginInterface.di

Here I declare :

```
extern (C): void performComputation(char lib[], char func[], void* ptr[], int varNum );
// lib and func will be used later
```

Then I have the corresponding C file: software_pluginInterface.c, 
where I declare :

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

void performComputation(char lib[], char func[], void * v[], int varNum)
{

  printf("there are %d variables \n", varNum);

}
```

Then I call this with :

```
performComputation(A, B, V, to!int(v.count()/3));
```

A, B are '\0' terminated char arrarys
V is a void pointer array with 6 elements

So I would expect a output like : there are 2 variables

But I am getting : there are 1557197040 variables

I have 64 bit OS, and I compile it all using (as in the other question)

```
gcc -c software_pluginInterface.c
dmd software.d software_pluginInterface.o
```

Then I call them using : ./software

PS: according to [this page](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html), D ints are same as C ints.

Comment: in d arrays have a length that is passed with them. try changing the declaration to use pointers instead

Comment: OH EM GEE... What can I say. I am a quater century old serious weatherman, who does a lot of programming, but now I am shouting like a 7 year old lass in a Justine Bieber Concert...

Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In D, an array consists of a pointer to some data, and a length, in C++, it's basically just a pointer. This means that your D function should be declared as:

```
extern (C): void performComputation(char* lib, char* func, void** ptr, int varNum );
```